# Parsing nested Data Structure of unknown type

Tags: data-structures, collections

In an attempt to not waste time, I was hoping someone here could readily identify the data structure presented below and if so, could you please tell me what it's called and where I might find an existent parser?

```
CumulativeData = {
    ["UnitedStates"] = {
        ["California"] = {
            [0] = {
                "777",
            },
            ["Flower"] = "Tulip",
            ["PoliticalAffiliation"] = 2,
            ["ZipCodes"] = {
                [0] = "35415",
                [1] = "54178",
                [2] = "65214",
                [3] = "58795",
            },
        },
        ["Wyoming"] = {
            [0] = {
                "888",
            },
            ["Flower"] = "Rose",
            ["PoliticalAffiliation"] = 1,
            ["ZipCodes"] = {
                [0] = "96325",
                [1] = "14685",
                    [2] = "52365",
                [3] = "85471",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a good phaser for JSON Data.

Good starting point is [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html). Json data structure can be very dynamic. You can access each entity as dynamic property of a class. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object/3806407)

Comment: Thanks for the attempted answer, but the above Data Structure isn't JSON, I had only mentioned JSON to explain how I wrote my own parser for JSON because I didn't know there were so many.

Comment: I see, perhaps this is JSON after all? I will mess with this parser and see if it works to parse this I had always seen JSON with :'s seperating key / value (not =) and never with []'s around them.

Comment: Since its slimier to JSON, workaround would be if you could find/write a translation or conversion from above data structure to JSON. Then it would give lot of flexibility. Converting = with : etc.